# Help me to delete Windows Boot Manager from grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I had an Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot. I deleted Windows 10, but in the grub menu it still shows the Windows Boot Manager. Can someone help me remove this option and login to Ubuntu directly?

Answer (score 0):

step 0: ensure you have valid, tested backups of anything you care about

1. Rename `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw`
2. Remove any Windows entries using `efibootmgr`. Directions are here https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples
3. do a `sudo update-grub`
4. reboot

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

1. edit `/etc/default/grub`  with sudo
2. set `grub_default` to number corresponding to ubuntu line entry in grub
3. reduce `grub_timeout` to 0

Save the file and update grub  `sudo update-grub`
This would make booting straight into ubuntu. Anytime you want to revert just increase grub_timeout > 0 and you will be able to select boot option in grub.

Comment: Considering the OP has already erased Windows files, Bill's suggestion sounds better.